# Commit to new gitHub repository without showing local commits

Tags: git, github, flask

I have searched Google and SO but have not found an answer I feel solves my issue.

I have a project on Flask. While building I used git locally to push to Heroku
 Now I want to push only the current version, showing none of the commits made locally to GitHub.
 Is this possible?

Comment: What do you mean by 'push only the current version'? Mean you have multiple commits in local, and you want to simplify commits into a single summary commit, then push latest code by this single commit?   If in this case, you can try `git rebase -i` to re-construct you local commit, you can easily find guideline of this command on internet.

Comment: Create a new repository in GitHub then drag and drop the project files. Done.

Comment: By push only the current version I mean I want none of the previous commits to be pushed to gitHub. No history.

Comment: Agreed @Kurtis. Also you can do this by git way: copy whole local project folder let's say `my-project-copy`, then deleted `.git` folder located at `my-project-copy/.git`. Now `my-project-copy` is a clean un-versioned workspace, then you can do a single commit, set github remote and push it.